# Regarding Applying validation in textbox through Regular Expression

Tags: asp.net, .net, regex, devexpress

I am trying to apply validation in Textbox control for limiting empty space in control. Following is the Regular Expression code I'm using:

```
Regularexpression validationexpression="^[^-\s][a-zA-Z0-9_\s-]+$" errortext="" />
```

Now my requirement is:

1. User should not enter empty space in begining. (Working fine)
2. Textbox limit is upto 10 numbers, user will able to enter as much as number he wants, no validation if he enter less than 10 numbers. (Working fine.)
3. validation should prompt if user enter the numbers like this "111
   111 ", means show validation if there is empty space between
   numbers. (Not working)

Currently I'm using following Regular Expression to achieve this thing, please let me know or update my regular expression so I can achieve this requirement.

```
Regularexpression validationexpression="^[^-\s][a-zA-Z0-9_\s-]+$" errortext="" />
```

Comment: Remove `\s` from your regular expression if you don't want to enter spaces

Comment: @Aman could you post some examples for matching and unmatching strings?

Comment: @WaqasRaja: Thanks for your quick reply but It's not worked according to my requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{1,10}$
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/wQ1oW3/23

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply but it's giving error when user enters 4 digits only, I have also need the user can enter digits upto 10 digits. Please help !

Comment: Thanks for your help, yes it's working fine, actually I had used the masking in devExpress textbox due to which the regular experession not working fine and giving issues. I have removed it now and it's working correctly. For limiting the length to 10 digits I have used the property MaxLength="10".

Answer (score 0):

you can use a regex like

```
^[^\s][\d\w_-]{1,10}$
```

which will match as

http://regex101.com/r/lK4pF7/1

how it works?

`^` asserts the pattern at the begining of the string.

`[^\s]` negation of `\s` validates those without an empty string at the begining

`[\d\w_-]` ensures that body contains only alphanum, _, - no spaces.

`{1,10}` minimum `1` and maximum `10` mathes, ensures length not greater than `10`

`$` asserts the pattern at end of string

Comment: Thanks for your help, yes it's working fine, actually I had used the masking in devExpress textbox due to which the regular experession not working fine and giving issues. I have removed it now and it's working correctly. For limiting the length to 10 digits I have used the property MaxLength="10". This solution also working fine but not able to mark this one also as solution and website allow me to only mark one answer as solution.